# Java ambiguous type for protected method

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, protected, ambiguous

I'm facing the following error-message by Eclipse:

> The method getString(String, BasicNameValuePair[]) is ambiguous for the type Class1

for the following code:

```
public final class Class1 {
    public static void getString(String requiredArguments, BasicNameValuePair[] dataPairs) {

    }

    protected static void getString(String requiredArguments, byte[] dataBytes) {

    }
}

public final class Class2 {
    public static void callTest() {
        Class1.getString("This is a test", null);
    }
}
```

The code in `callTest()` will result in the error above.

It's clear that `null` can be converted to `BasicNameValuePair[]` aswell as to `byte[]`, but note the `protected` modifier here. The method with `byte[]` as argument shouldn't be visible to `Class2` at all and thus not be ambiguous.

Why is the protected method visible to other (not subclassed) classes and causing this error?

Comment: Where is `Class2` relative to `Class1`? In the same package?

Comment: Yes they are in the same package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because these classes are on the same package?

> The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed
>   within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by
>   a subclass of its class in another package.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: That was the reason. Thank you!